# How to see an overview of the download statistics of all modules on drupal.org?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

At the moment the [usage overview page](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage) on drupal.org gives an idea of the number of sites using a certain module. However as noted this includes information from only sites that include the update status module which means it is biased toward newer sites, is there a way to see an overview of the download statistics of a module as well in a similar view?

Comment: Seems we have an [API](https://www.drupal.org/api) from drupal.org we can hook into pull this information across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, d.o. has an [API](https://www.drupal.org/api) from which you can retrieve project information. For your purposes, you can retrieve module downloads with the following URL:

```
https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node.json?type=project_module
```

The JSON output has a property called `list` which is an array of node objects for each module project. Each node object contains a property called `field_download_count` that contains the project's download count.

Note: results are paged (100 per result) from the web service so you'll have to iterate through 307 pages of results to get all module projects (the JSON output contains a `first`, `last`, `prev`, `next` property with URLs that let you navigate through the pages)

Answer (score 3):

You can get information about a particular module in both `XML` and `JSON` format by accessing URL:

**Eg: (For Views Module) :**

*XML format:*

https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node.xml?field_project_machine_name=views

*JSON format:*

https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node.json?field_project_machine_name=views

---

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/api